# apollo graphql response data doesn't update on network error

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I have a simple graphQl query life below

```
export function () {
   const {data: usersData, loading, refetch, networkStatus } = useQuery(USERS_QUERY, {
   context: { headers: { 'accept-language': locale}},
   variables: props.variables,
   fetchPolicy: 'network-only
  });

 return (usersData?.map(.....))
}
```

My query works fine. However, when there is a network issue or internet failure for example, the old data still remain despite the fact that the `networkStatus` changing to 2. Is there any way to make the data update when the network fail? Considering networkStatus already changed, why is data cached ? Any help would be appreciated.